# Anyway to add a new row to a 2d array with less entries than the first? (blueJ)

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, bluej

is there any way to create a new row in a 2d array which has a smaller capacity than the first row,

for example having a row like so

{{10},{12},{13}}

and then with a second row the array being,

{{10},{12},{13}},

```
 {{14},{15}}
```

is this at all possible?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can:

```
String[] array1 = {"1","2","3"};
String[] array2 = {"7","8"};

 String[][] arrays = { array1, array2 };
 System.out.println(arrays.length);
 System.out.println(arrays[0].length + " - " +  Arrays.toString(arrays[0]));
 System.out.println(arrays[1].length + " - " +  Arrays.toString(arrays[1]));
```

However it doesn't mean you should. The bugs from using arrays in such a way could be very frustrating. You'll need to check the length on each use.  Consider using *Collections* instead.